# Java BeautyEye look and feel empty JMenuBar items

Tags: java, linux, swing, java-8, look-and-feel

I am using [BeautyEye](https://code.google.com/p/beautyeye/) look and feel in a Java Desktop program but recently found out JMenuBar shows empy JMenuItems as shown in the screenshot below.

As you can see the area of the menu is there but with the same colour as the Jframe contentPane and with no Menu text visible.

[image: empty menubar example]

a sample program to test this (download the BeautyEye library from [here](https://code.google.com/p/beautyeye/)) is:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import org.jb2011.lnf.beautyeye.BeautyEyeLNFHelper;

public class JavaMenuBarExample implements Runnable
{
  private JFrame frame;
  private JMenuBar menuBar;
  private JMenu fileMenu;
  private JMenuItem openMenuItem;

  public static void main(String[] args)
  { 
    try
        {
            BeautyEyeLNFHelper.frameBorderStyle = BeautyEyeLNFHelper.FrameBorderStyle.osLookAndFeelDecorated;
            org.jb2011.lnf.beautyeye.BeautyEyeLNFHelper.launchBeautyEyeLNF();
            UIManager.put("RootPane.setupButtonVisible", Boolean.FALSE);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    // the proper way to show a jframe (invokeLater)
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new JavaMenuBarExample());
  }

  @Override
  public void run()
  {
    frame = new JFrame("Java Menubar Example");
    menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
    openMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Open");
    fileMenu.add(openMenuItem);
    // add menus to menubar
    menuBar.add(fileMenu);
    // put the menubar on the frame
    frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 300));
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Comment: Your code is working here as expected. Win7, Java 7 and the PLAF from `beautyeye_lnf_v3.5_all_in_one.zip`.

Comment: Linux, Java 8 and the PLAF from beautyeye_lnf_v3.5_all_in_one.zip not working :(

Comment: Does this issue also appear with the demo application [SwingSets3(BeautyEyeLNFDemo).jar](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JackJiang2011/beautyeye/master/demo2/SwingSets3(BeautyEyeLNFDemo).jar)

Comment: Very Interesting question, the issue doesn't appear with the BeautyEye demo! yet with the SSCE shown in my question it appears.

Comment: Note that your SSCE replaces the look-and-feel on a background thread and not on the EDT. Do you have the same issue when doing everything on the EDT ?

Comment: @saimiris_devel I run your example in a Gnome 3 environment. If I use OpenJRE 8 I have the same issue as you show in the screenshot. If I use Oracle JRE 8 the menu is displayed as expected.

Comment: I double checked with a System.out.println(rn.getSpecVendor()+" "+rn.getVmVendor()+" "+rn.getVmVersion()+" "+rn.getSpecVersion()); and it returns Oracle Corporation Oracle Corporation 25.45-b02 1.8, so I'm using Oracle JDK 1.8.0_45 already unfortunately.

Comment: @Robin moved the try/catch which sets LAF inside the run() method which is inside EDT and nothing changes unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been debug it use jdk 1.8_u45, it is normal at Windows platform.
I guess this may be a bug for linux platform java1.8_u45.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am the author of BeautyEye project.

A few things to note：

1. BeautyEye has migrated to
   GitHub: https://github.com/JackJiang2011/beautyeye, you can find
   the latest version there. But I'm so sorry, there is no English
   introduction.
2. Because the JDK version updates too fast, I just
   do few tests with jdk8 (and just for Windows), so I can't guarantee
   full compatibility with jdk8 in all platform temporarily.
3. I think that problem is caused by Java transparent API, you can fetch the latest source code to debug it: for example use system frame style but not use transparent frame border etc.

You can contact me at `jb2011 at 163.com`, I hope you can resolve this issue.

Comment: I fetched the latest source code and compiled my example under GNU/Linux and Java 1.8 and it seems to be fixed!

Comment: I have problems building the dist jar of the project, it gives compilation errors such as " error: package sun.swing.table does not exist", according to Oracle FAQ http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-sun-packages-142232.html "A Java program that directly calls into sun.* packages is not guaranteed to work on all Java-compatible platforms. "